# Run uninstaller and wait until terminated

Tags: installshield

all/
There is app, installer for app is created by InstallShield (*not* msi project)
I need uninstall app and wait until uninstaller terminated.

I read registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{MyAppGuid}, UninstallString and try start uninstaller

in my case UninstallString = "C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information{9F2A3D76-7785-492F-89E5-3F0FE2D205DC}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0419  -removeonly

but in cmd.exe
"start /wait {UninstallerString}" don't wait until uninstaller terminated. I think uninstaller run same temp exe and terminated immediately. but then how can I resolve ny problem? Any idea??

Comment: what are you trying to say? you mean you need to uninstall first and proceed with the installation? can you please be clear.

Comment: hm, sorry for my Engish.I need to start uninstall and wait until uninstaller is done

Comment: you want to initiate uninstall during installation? have you tried LaunchAppAndWait ?

Answer (score 1):

Installshield added a `/clone_wait` switch at some point which solves your problem, as seen [here](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm#wp1039966):

`This parameter indicates that the original setup should wait for the cloned setup process to complete before exiting.`

Your uninstall string will look like this:

```
UninstallString = "C:\Program Files\...\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0419 -removeonly /clone_wait
```

`-clone_wait` will probably work too but I've tested and used it with `/clone_wait`.